# TensorFlow serving vs TensorFlow service

Tags: python, tensorflow, service, server, production

I have a question regarding the difference between `TensorFlow Serving` versus `TensorFlow service`. (Sorry that I'm not familiar with this at all.)

I found TensorFlow serving's definition, which is "TensorFlow Serving is a flexible, high-performance serving system for machine learning models, designed for production environments."(https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/)
While I'm wondering what TensorFlow service is? Such as in this sentences:

"TensorFlow models can be deployed to production services like **TensorFlow service**, and mobile devices."

And what are the production services?
I guess the TensorFlow service refers to some service that helps manage TensorFlow, rather than TensorFlow Serving which is a system to deploy the TensorFlow model. Is that correct?
I'm confused about what the TensorFlow service is, can you share some light on it?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Look up (TensorFlow) master and worker services in [TensorFlow Architecture](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/architecture).

Answer (score 0):

I think tensorflow serving is the system that enables us to deploy tf models easily without hustle and bustle (eg. by using saved model we don't need to specify model architecture on production) while tensorflow service is something like Google ML engine.

ps: Don't take my words for it :)